# Using ngMap in gulp project - build failing - getting 'google' is not defined

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I've set up an angular project using Yeoman, and embedding a google map in a page using [ngmap](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps), using a given address to centre it. I'm adding a marker to the map using the google geocode service to get the latitude/longitude for the address, once the map has been initialised.

```
var vm = this;
vm.address = '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500, United States';
NgMap.getMap().then(function() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: vm.address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    vm.markerPosition = '[' + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + ', ' + results[0].geometry.location.lng() + ']';
    } else {
    console.log("Unable to retrive details for address: " + address);
    }
  });
});
```

It's working fine, I've a plunkr running here - https://plnkr.co/Ex91VGqdFmL9FP78uzU0?p=preview - but when I run the build using gulp build I get this error, and the same when I run the unit tests:

```
'google' is not defined
```

What do I need to inject, or mock, so that the call to google.maps.Geocoder doesn't fail?

As requested, this is the index.html from the build

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title translate>title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor-d41d8cd98f.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-2dd2bcbbbd.css">
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <main ui-view></main>
  </body>
  <script src="scripts/vendor-83b6c91f4a.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/app-41321c4301.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the page after you've used gulp build?  Usually an error message like this indicates the function is being called before the Google Maps JavaScript API has finished loading.

Comment: sure, I've added the index.html created after the build completes to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through some of the examples of ngMap and it turns out the marker directive can take an address as a parameter, which it converts to lat/lon values automatically. 
So the solution is to remove all the google.maps.Geocoder and just this in the html.

```
<marker position="{{myMapCtrl.address}}" title="Marker"></marker>
```

and to learn to read **all** the documentation before attempting to use a library